# Security of Blowfish with secret S-boxes

Tags: block-cipher, s-boxes, feistel-network, blowfish

There are similar questions about secret S-box(es), but none of them about secret Blowfish (or any other canonical Feistel cipher) S-Boxes, only about secret AES S-Box.

Let's suppose that instead of using Pi hexadecimal number in Blowfish S-Boxes, I use my own S-Box taken from /dev/random and keep it secret.

Blowfish modifies all the 32-bits halves of plaintext 16 times, each half gets 8 inputs 32-bits each from the F-function (totaling 256-bits).

Does keeping the S-Boxes secret improves security of Blowfish by 256-bits?

/\ As each half of plaintext receives 8 32-bits words from the F-function in which the S-boxes are processed, the entire plaintext is modified 8 times considering the two halves concatenated in a 64-bt block, receiving a total of 256-bits from the F-function.

Comment: As in DES research has shown that Random S-Boxes are not as secure as the design. You are asking obscuring the design that is not the way in the cryptography in which the only key is secret by Kerckhoff's principles...

Comment: Blowfish already has secret S-boxes for encryption. Those Pi S-boxes are used for generating secret S-boxes and subkeys from key. You could replace them and keep them secret, but you probably wouldn't gain much.

Comment: There might be chosen-key attacks to recover S-boxes like for GOST block cipher, but GOST has smaller S-boxes. However Blowfish already has big key and its block size is too small anyway.

Comment: Also it could be hard to keep S-boxes secret. If you distribute binary, it can be extracted.

Comment: @kelalaka Bruce Schneier said that Blowfish can be implemented with smaller S-boxes and also, the first Blowfish implementation written by him, used only zeroes as initial S-Boxes (encryption with supplied key over zeroes).